# AutoCompleteTextView.isPopupShowing() is always FALSE

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to find out if **AutoCompleteTextView** dropdown is shown/hidden. On button click I want to show dropdown (if it's hidden), and hide it (if it's showing). For this purpose I use method `isPopupShowing()`, but it always returning **FALSE**.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == button.getId()) {

        if (autoCompleteTextView.isPopupShowing()) {
            autoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
        } else {
            autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When AutoCompleteTextView lost focus, the dropdown disappears. So the dropdown is always invisible when you click the button.

Simply add a new boolean property to your listener to remember last state.

Answer (score 0):

Code in Kotlin

```
val afill = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.myTextId)
var showAFill = false

afill.addTextChangedListener (object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
         showAFill = afill.isPopupShowing
    }
    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)
    }
})

afill.onItemClickListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        showAFill = false
    }
}
```

If you click on any element in autofill it will close.

```
showAutofill.setOnClickListener { _ ->
    if (showAFill) afill.dismissDropDown()
    else afill.showDropDown()
    showAFill = !showAFill
}
```

showAutofill - id of my button on layout